# Driver information for Appium Android

Tags: android, rspec, capybara, appium

I have a test suite setup using rspec and capybara. I wish to use Appium to run my tests using the android emulators.

What is the driver information for android? For iOS I have this:

```
  desired_caps_ios = {
      platform:        "Mac",
      deviceName:      "iPhone Simulator",
      platformName:    "iOS",
      platformVersion: "6.1",
      app:             "path to app"
  }

  url = "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub" # or a sauce labs url

  Capybara.register_driver(:appium) do |app|
    appium_lib_options = {
        server_url:           url
    }
    all_options = {
        appium_lib:  appium_lib_options,
        caps:        desired_caps_ios
    }
    Appium::Capybara::Driver.new app, all_options
  end

  Capybara.default_driver = :appium
```

Anyone have any idea? I have looked around but can't seem to find the correct info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After much searching around various forums I managed to get the correct info for ruby/rspec. Please see below for what I used:

```
  desired_caps_android = {
        deviceName:      "Droid",
        platformName:    "Android",
        platformVersion: "4.2",
        deviceType:      "phone",
        app:             "path to your app"
    }


  url = "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub" 


  Capybara.register_driver(:appium) do |app|
    appium_lib_options = {
        server_url:           url
    }
    all_options = {
        appium_lib:  appium_lib_options,
        caps:        desired_caps_android
    }
    Appium::Capybara::Driver.new app, all_options
  end

  Capybara.default_driver = :appium
```

Please note the "Droid" entry above is what I called my android emulator image.

Answer (score -1):

These capabilities worked for me ...

```
    AppiumDriver driver;
    URL url;

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");

    try 
    {
        url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver(url, capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("URL init error");
    }
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ram. However I am still having problems. When I enter the above I get a message stating: `method_missing': driver is nil. called capabilities (RuntimeError)

Comment: Do I still need to register the driver as per the ios example I gave above? (i.e - Capybara.register_driver(:appium) do |app|)

Comment: Don't know much about rspec and capyabara . but i have added the java code that i use ..

Comment: For the java code , i had to use java-client-1.5.0 and selenium 2.42.2 jar else the AppiumDriver method was not found NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: For the java code , i had to use java-client-1.5.0 and selenium 2.42.2 jar else the AppiumDriver method was not found NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Thanks Ram! I searched around some more and I found the correct capabilities for ruby. I have added it as an answer to the question.